# FreeRADIUS Certificate Based Authentication WiFi

Tags: certificate, freeradius, meraki

We are currently trying to deploy a new SSID for BYOD devices. The plan is to host a FreeRADIUS (CA) server and generate a certificate which can be shared to all staff and can be imported onto their devices.

Is it solution feasible? If yes, does anyone have a guide on how to do it? I've searched online but the term radius is so broad.